# Is it possible to copy debug data from VS to Linqpad?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linqpad

I like linqpad, but often when I need it, I have some data in Visual studio that I need to do stuff with.

Therefore I would love to know if it is possible to copy some list of data into Linqpad, creating the necessary classes and inserting the same values into the list, so I have real data to work with

So I would debug and get something like this in a breakpoint:

[image]

I then want those 5 items in a list in linqpad that I can work with

Comment: I don't think a trivial work, either in VS or LinqPad. Can you try immediate window in such case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [LINQBridgeVs](https://github.com/codingadventures/LINQBridgeVs), it's a VS Extension that allows you to launch LINQPad from the VS debugger copying a complex data type over to a new LINQPad snippet along with the debug time data.

1. After installing the extension, enable the solution you're debugging, click the magnifier dropdown for the complex type and click LINQBridgeVS Visualizer from the context menu.

[image]

2. A new snippet will be opened in LINQPad with the data structure and debug time data ready to go.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! That sounds like exactly what I need

Comment: Hmm maybe the project is dead, he promised VS2015 support in December which is still not there, hopefully he comes back :)

Comment: Not sure if they're thinking it's less useful in VS2015 where the immediate window supports things like lambda expressions now, or if they are still planning on updating.

Comment: @Mech0z I'm the author of LINQBridgeVs, I've abandoned working on it for quite some time. I've added support to VS2017 and LINQPad 5, there is a pre-release version on the GitHub page: https://github.com/codingadventures/LINQBridgeVs/releases/tag/1.4.2

Comment: Cool will take a look at it :)